# Powers of dimensionless quantities: is this a bug?

Tags: units

Today I came across the following behavior:

```
Quantity[x, "Minutes"/"Minutes"]^-1
(* Quantity[1/x, (1/#1 &)[("Minutes")/("Minutes")]] *)
```

It seems that Mathematica inverts both the unit and magnitude, but since `Quantity` has `HoldRest`, the unit does not evaluate further.  This only seems to occur when taking a power of a dimensionless `Quantity` where at least one of the units cancels:

```
Quantity[a, "Meters" "Seconds"/"Minutes"/"Meters"]^2
```

exhibits this behavior, but

```
Quantity[a, "Meters" "Seconds"/"Minutes"/"Inches"]^2
```

and

```
Quantity[a, "Meters" "Seconds"/"Minutes"]^2
```

do not.

I feel like Mathematica should be able to handle this situation correctly.  Should I report this?

(This is not actually a problem for me.  I discovered this by accident when evaluating "100 km / 1200 m/min" as natural language input: Mathematica interprets "m/min" as `"Minutes"/"Minute"`).

(Mathematica 10.0.1.0, Windows 8.1 64-bit)

Comment: In 10.1 `Quantity[a, "Meters" "Seconds"/"Minutes"/"Meters"]^2` `==` `Quantity[a^2/3600, "PureUnities"]`. A `UnitSimplify` on the result of the second gives `Quantity[(62500*a^2)/145161, "PureUnities"]`. The last ends up as `Quantity[a^2/3600, "Meters"^2]`. I seems that it is fixed in 10.1 but that shouldn't stop you reporting for 10.0.1.

Comment: @Edmund If they fixed it in a later release wouldn't reporting it be redundant?  Unless they use a time machine to go back and fix it before my school decided not to update to 10.2 =)

Comment: Do they cease all support on later versions when they come out with a new one? Actually, that seems it could be the case now that I think about it. Its one method of getting you to upgrade. =)

Comment: @Edmund I guess what I'm saying is if they fix any bugs in 10.0.1, they'd release an update; which they already did, 10.1.0.  They won't re-release 10.0.1.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is (was) a bug or not. Yes, the units formally cancel, but when one encounters quantities like this (such as sheet resistance, ohm-metres per metre), it doesn't always make logical or physical sense to do so because the quantities cancelling are not related.